# PDF to HTML converter - Stuck

Tags: html, converters, pdf-to-html

I need to have just one pdf on my website and HTML file. I dont need to be making them on my website I just need to add one pdf to a page and put text over it. Does anyone know of the best way to convert the pdf to HTML. I have found places like cloud converter but it adds so much other stuff on the page with the text that it is impossible to filter through all the css and javascript to find ways to put text over it without it covering it up or weird characteristics arising. I just need the text to be formatted relative to itself and on the page plainly in html. Is this even the right approach. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use PDF.js to statically convert a PDF to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785198/use-pdf-js-to-statically-convert-a-pdf-to-html)

Comment: 1. https://pdf.co/samples/pdf-co-web-api-pdf-to-html-api-javascript-convert-pdf-to-html-in-jquery 2. https://bytescout.com/products/developer/cloudapi/how-to-pdf-to-html-in-javascript-and-jquery-using-cloud-api-low-level

Comment: @rzlvmp I'm looking more for a converter online, I cant currently integrate one into my website so it would need to be external. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @k J I need a pdf I have downloaded to be displayed on my html page. Since I dont need to do this 20 more times and it is just one PDF I'm working with I was wondering if you have a link to a pdf to html converter that will convert my html to pdf but not like cloud convert does because it adds too many other things and doesnt allow me to add text over it. I have been about 2 pages back on google and still have no luck. Wondering if anyone has any other information.